# Object is created. (RoR, Database Cleaner, Factory Girl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-cleaner

I'm a beginner in Rails, help me, I do not understand what the problem is. It seems like something else is written before(:each)...
And How can I write a test in test_spac.rb in which no Card object is created. That the method before(:each) did not work for this test.

This is work:

test_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Index Page" do

  before(:each) do
    @card = FactoryGirl.create(:card)
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  it "shows error messages if translation is wrong" do
    visit root_path
    fill_in 'translated_text', with: 'wqww'
    click_on 'Проверить'
    expect(page).to have_content('Неверно!')
  end

  after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

rails_helper.rb:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'database_cleaner'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist


Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :features) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

This is NOT Work:

test_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Index Page" do

  before(:each) do
    @card = FactoryGirl.create(:card)
  end

  it "shows error messages if translation is wrong" do
    visit root_path
    fill_in 'translated_text', with: 'wqww'
    click_on 'Проверить'
    expect(page).to have_content('Неверно!')
  end

end
```

rails_helper.rb:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :features) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.start
      end

  config.after(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

I make this: (test_spec.rb)
require 'rails_helper'

```
describe "Index Page" do

  it "check behavior then translation is wrong" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:card) #################
    visit root_path
    fill_in 'translated_text', with: 'some text'
    click_on 'Проверить'
    expect(page).to have_content('Неверно!')
  end


  it "check page then object is not created" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content('Непросмотренных')
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post what you mean by not working? Are you getting any error messages?

By the way, why do you have `config.use_transactional_fixtures` disabled? If you stick to using `before(:each)` hooks, RSpec will [reset the database for you](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions) and you shouldn't need to use the `DatabaseCleaner`.

Comment: Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to found field 'translated_text' Page is load without form. (because form is load only when object is created)

Comment: The reason because I have disabled config.use_transactional_fixtures is because I need to manage database strategy in future.

Comment: @VladimirFomin Have you tried the second (non-working) version when not using the `DatabaseCleaner`?